# Horizontal Scroll View with image and text

Tags: android, xml, horizontal-scrolling, sliding

I am developing one application. In application I want to slide images horizontally like an *E-commerce* applications. I don't have any idea how to implement this.

Can anyone please suggest me how to achieve this in application.

[I want sliding of images like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fI5lz.jpg)

Comment: You can use custom view of Horizontal Listview.

Comment: You can check this Link :[http://sandyandroidtutorials.blogspot.in/2013/06/horizontal-listview-tutorial.html](http://sandyandroidtutorials.blogspot.in/2013/06/horizontal-listview-tutorial.html)

Comment: I tried this link already. But its not working

Comment: you can use DevsmartAndroid. It is working as horizontal list view . Its can help you. .

Comment: What is issues with HorizontalListview?..Any error?

Comment: I tried to set the json values. but i dint get

Answer (score 0):

```
 <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/hsv"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="150sp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:measureAllChildren="false"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="130sp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_margin="10sp"
                android:gravity="center|left"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageview1"
                    android:layout_width="100sp"
                    android:layout_height="100sp"
                    android:src="@drawable/uploadepic"
                    android:layout_margin="5sp"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image1"
                    android:layout_width="120sp"
                    android:layout_height="100sp"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:layout_margin="5sp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image2"
                    android:layout_width="120sp"
                    android:layout_height="100sp"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:layout_margin="5sp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image3"
                    android:layout_width="120sp"
                    android:layout_height="100sp"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:layout_margin="5sp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image4"
                    android:layout_width="120sp"
                    android:layout_height="100sp"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:layout_margin="5sp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image5"
                    android:layout_width="120sp"
                    android:layout_height="100sp"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5sp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20sp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: I am parsing Images from the json. So i want to scroll those images in horizontal view

Comment: Yes, you have to create ImageView Dynamically and setImage on Image View and Add it to HorizontalscrollView Dynamically

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a recycler view and set the orientation to Layout Manager.

You can see a nice example about reycler view here, you have to change the layout manager's orientation as I said above. : 
[RecyclerView simple list](http://www.jayway.com/2014/12/23/android-recyclerview-simple-list/)